# how to get a scrollable div in Android

Tags: android, css, html, scroll

i added a `div` with a lot of data in it, and it works fine on a PC and on the Blackberry, but it doesn't work on Android: The data is retrieved with no problems but the `div` isn't scrollable.

Here is the HTML code:

```
    <div id="scroll">
      <div runat="server" ID="view"></div>
    </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
    #view 
    {
      position: absolute;
      top: 15%;
      left: 0.9%;
      width: 98.3%;
      height: 75%;
      font-family: Calibri;
      font-size: 0.5em;
      white-space: pre-wrap;
      border: 1px solid black;
      overflow: auto;
      padding: 0.2em;
    }
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to do this on a native android application, you're going to have to implement a ScrollView:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a creative work-around (that works on Android (2.3.5 Gingerbread) and Firefox browser for Android).

I didn't have the problem reported here on the first site I did but had issues on the second. After finding this answers here I remembered the old site worked so I checked what I did there. Copying over old to new site I was able to fix my problem...

This works on Android/Firefox browser but does not put a scroll bar indicator on screen (but touch-drag scrolls the content down the .

What WORKED for me is dual  Tags... EMBED code to scroll in a second  tag.

<**div** style="**width: 100%**; **height: 100%**; background-color:#fdc4f6; border: solid 1px #000;">

<**div** style="**overflow:scroll; height:350px**; text-align:left; padding: 1em 4em 0 4em;"> [Content will scroll if text overflows div on Android now]

then close DIV tags now the content in the second

may not be the prettiest code or method to use, but it got the job done for me (although I haven't tested in iOS devices).

For what it's worth...
-LB-

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color:#fdc4f6; border: solid 1px #000;"><div style="overflow:scroll; height:350px; text-align:left; padding: 1em 4em 0 4em;"> [Content will scroll if text overflows div on Android now]</div></div>
```